# Convert First Order Logic to Clause Form - Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

I am trying to implement a function that takes FOL sentence and returns an equivalent one in clause form. Any idea for links,samples as I can't find any so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try developing further from https://code.google.com/p/aima-java/source/browse/trunk/aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/logic/fol/kb/FOLKnowledgeBase.java?r=1011 . Good luck!